# How to make QtCreator CMake build depend on another CMake project?

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, qt-creator

I have a CMake project that produces a static library. It compiles fine in QtCreator and produces the library in build dir. The `CMakeLists.txt` for the static library looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(mystaticlib VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

file(GLOB mystaticlib_SRC "src/**.cpp")
add_library( mystaticlib STATIC
    ${mystaticlib_SRC}
)
target_include_directories( mystaticlib PRIVATE include/mystaticlib INTERFACE include )
```

Now I have a Qt application project and I'd like to make it so that it depends on the other one - meaning I can do something like in the QtProject:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(MyQtProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

# This is how I imagine it working, not an actual code
include_project(mystaticlib, "~/my_projects/mystaticlib/CMakeLists.txt")
set(HEADERS_mystaticlib get_project_headers(mystaticlib))
# end of made up code
add_executable(MyQtProjectEXE ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MyQtProjectEXE mystaticlib)
target_include_directories(MyQtProjectEXE HEADERS_mystaticlib)
```

How can I get something like that? In practice, I'd like it to work so that the dependent project directory can be set to whatever during cmake configure step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely interested in [`add_subdirectory`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_subdirectory.html).

If the containing subdirectory has a `CMakeLists.txt` then by:

```
add_subdirectory("./path/to/the/directory")
```

You will include all targets defined in that `CMakeLists.txt` file.

All you have to do is add a dependency by using `target_link_libraries`. CMake will then understand that the subdirectory needs to be build beforehand.

---

EDIT: To use your project as an example:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)

project(MyQtProject VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

# This is how I imagine it working, not an actual code


#if the path is a subdirectory within the current folder
add_subdirectory("./local_path/to/mystaticlib")
#if not you need to specify a binary dir
add_subdirectory("/absolute/path/to/mystaticlib" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mystaticlib")


set(HEADERS_mystaticlib get_project_headers(mystaticlib))
# end of made up code
add_executable(MyQtProjectEXE ${PROJECT_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(MyQtProjectEXE mystaticlib)
#...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I wish I posted the question sooner instead of 1 hour of googling. One more thing: you might want to remove `set(HEADERS_...` that's made up code I conjured, not a real part of the project. All I needed was to add subdirectory and add link library.